# Why Blender 2.82 overwrite my picture?

Tags: rendering

I downloaded new Blender 2.82 today and while working on one computer, I started rendering on another. All the time the same settings, no overwriting!!! and I usually have from frame 1 to frame 1 and hit render animation. I was so happy with the result few minutes before render was done. I came back to see final render image and I saw new rendering is running, overwriting… OMG!!! What is going on? never happened before, maybe one or two times, but I had overwriting on. NOT THIS TIME! Is it possible to find te render done? I tried, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a setting called [*Overwrite*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html?highlight=overwrite#output-panel) in the *Output Properties* which allows to disable the overwriting of existing files, when unchecked. Unfortunately files that have already been overwritten cannot be recovered.

[image: Disable Overwrite]

Comment: I know that. I had this off. I am tired and I will try to find out all tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I am back and as a member. I found out the reason why I had problem like this.

Newly instaled Blender 2.82 on one computer (I applied new settings on first computer) found 4 "old layers"(scenes) saved in a file made in Blender 2.79b and started to render new project 4 times.

I wanted to use one model I created for a long time ago in Blender 2.79b. I had two copies of this file and I decided to open one and selected parts of a model I wanted, inverted selection and deleted every other objects (after unhiding everything).

I saved/overwrote this in Blender 2.81 first. I cleaned up the file from information about deleted objects, materials in *Orphan Data* Outliner mode. But I did not check Scenes. I worked on this model and new project in 2.81. I was satisfied with better look of it and suddenly I saw Blender 2.82 is for download and I did it and started to render the project.

On second computer I accidentally overwrote my settings from 2.81 and rendering was OK. I was shocked when I saw that the first computer is overwriting the render. It stopped it and after som time I took some tests with low sampling and realized that it is overwriting four times and saving at the end one render.

After all I saw these scenes in *Outliner*. I knew it was from old file and it does not matter that I took the overwriting function off.

[image]